# How to avoid paragraph marks?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this routine that works well, but it messes up as it counts paragraph marks.  How can I skip paragraph marks?

```
        For Each wrd In ActiveDocument.Words
            If Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal") Then
               If wrd.Font.Name <> "Arial" Or wrd.Font.Size < 9 Or wrd.Font.Size = 11 Or wrd.Font.Size > 12 _
                Or wrd.Font.Color <> wdColorBlack Or wrd.Font.Color <> wdColorAutomatic Or wdColorBlue Then
                    wrd.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
                    wordrep = wordrep + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
For Each wrd In ActiveDocument.Words
    If Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal") Then
        If wrd.Font.Name <> "Arial" Or _
           wrd.Font.Size < 9 Or _
           wrd.Font.Size = 11 Or _
           wrd.Font.Size > 12 _
           Or wrd.Font.Color <> wdColorBlack Or _
           wrd.Font.Color <> wdColorAutomatic Or _
           wrd.Font.Color <> wdColorBlue Then
                If Asc(Left(wrd, 1)) <> 13 Then
                    wrd.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
                    wordrep = wordrep + 1
                End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This worked perfect as usual, Siddharth!  Many thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with your logic. What do you mean by `Or wdColorBlue Then`? This won't work as intended...

If you mean `wrd.Font.Color <> wdColorBlue`: The font color can't be both black and blue at the same time, so `wrd.Font.Color <> wdColorBlack Or wrd.Font.Color <> wdColorBlue` will *always* be true! Therefore the contents of your inner `If` construct will always execute.

If you mean `wrd.Font.Color = wdColorBlue`: When the font is blue, then it is necessarily not black, so the `wrd.Font.Color <> wdColorBlack` condition is redundant and superfluous.

I don't know whether this addresses your problem... I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "it messes up as it counts paragraph marks".